# Laravel 8 Vue Axios upload multiple files

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple files using axios and vue.

This is the template. I used no form since I want to dynamically update each field.

```html
<input
  @change="setFiles"
  ref="files"
  name="file-upload"
  type="file"
  class="sr-only"
  multiple />

<button
    @click="submitFiles"
    type="submit"
  Upload files
</button>
```

This is my frontend axios logic:

```js
export default {
  props: [
    'customer'
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      attachments: [],
      confirmingPassword: false,
      form: {
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        infotext: '',
        current_status: '',
        files: [],
      },
      files: new FormData
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFiles(e) {
      let selectedFiles = e.target.files;

      if(!selectedFiles.length) {
        return false;
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < this.$refs.files.files.length; i++){
        this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
      }
    },
    submitFiles() {
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": undefined } };

      this.files.append('files[]', this.attachments)

      axios.post('/customers/upload', this.files, config);
    }
  }
```

In my laravel backend route I am trying to save it like this:

```php
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $requestedFiles = $request->all()['files'];
     
    foreach ($requestedFiles as $requestedFileKey => $requestedFileValue) {
        Storage::disk('spaces')->putFile('uploads', $requestedFileValue, 'public');
    }
}
```

Which in returns give me following error:

> message: "The file "[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]" does not exist"

Comment: I think your problem is that you are doing `"Content-Type": undefined`, why ? You should be using `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Update  `const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": undefined } };` to  `const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"} } `

Comment: @matiaslauriti this causes the same error, undefined lets the browser choose which Content type I need. But again both return same error

Comment: Furthermore is returns this error `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
null`

Comment: That is really strange, you should not need to even define that config... You are doing something wrong that you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` as matias mentioned in comment,

```
  const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };

  this.files.append('files[]', this.attachments)

  axios.post('/customers/upload', this.files, config);
```

Then I think it's better to use `$request->file()` and `hasFile()` to check file exist or not:

```
if($request->hasFile('files'))
{
    $files = $request->file('files');   

    foreach ($files as $file) {
       Storage::disk('spaces')->putFile('uploads', $file, 'public');
    }
}
```

or if your storage is local:

```
   foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $name);
    }
```

Comment: This does also not work `dd($request->file('files'))`returns null

Comment: Furthermore is returns this error `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
null`

Comment: If I revert the content type again to undefined my `dd`returns `array:1 [
  0 => []
]` any empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData to submit the form through axios.

```
//Vue
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('files[]', this.$refs.files.files)
axios.post('/customers/upload', formData)
```

In your laravel controller you must capture the data through the request

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
    $files = $request->file('files');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $path = Storage::putFile('/public/files', $file);
        $url = Storage::url($path);
    }
}
```

This will save the files to the */store/app /public/files/* directory and name it automatically. Don't forget to run `php artisan storage:link` to create the symbolic link in your public directory

If you want to save the location of the file for access, the `$url` variable should work, as it contains the direct link including the host of your application.

Comment: This way `dd($request->file('files'))` returns null any idea?

Comment: Furthermore is returns this error `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
null`

Comment: If I revert the content type again to undefined my `dd`returns `array:1 [
  0 => []
]` any empty array